# PyQt5 QGroupBox with checkbox - disable checkbox only not the child widgets

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgroupbox

in pyqt5 if i have a checkable QGroupBox. Is there any easy way to disable only the checkbox (True - False) but not the child widgets of QGroupBox?

Comment: You already asked this question...

Comment: It's very similar but i don't want: `self.toggled.connect(self.toggleCheckBoxes)` but something like `self.setEnabledChanged.connect(self.toggleCheckBoxes)`

Comment: What can i do for this? I may build the changeEvent def method.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I want to disable the checkbox functionallity programmatically, with no change the child widgets. I want to user to not have the ability to click and change the state of checkbox. But i want the checkbox to be there.

Comment: In this link:https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-3565 says that QAction::changed is emitted in that case.

Comment: Just change the behavior of `toggleCheckBoxes` and ensure that the child widgets are enabled anyway. That bug report is irrelevant, QGroupBox has no action, and the change affects the children, not the group box.

Comment: Is this relative? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853046/re-send-an-event-to-a-newly-enabled-child-widget

Comment: the toggleCheckBoxes with some changes is almost ok, the problem is in the event which may i use to run the method.

Comment: Then please update the question with a valid [mre] and we'll eventually reopen it.